# Rails 3 - no such file to load -- openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, openssl, rvm

when running a Rails server, I get the following error:
no such file to load -- openssl

I try a solution I find online. I go to ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-head/ext/openssl. I type : ruby extconf.rb, but I get the following:

```
=== OpenSSL for Ruby configurator ===
=== Checking for system dependent stuff... ===
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for assert.h... yes
=== Checking for required stuff... ===
checking for openssl/ssl.h... no
=== Checking for required stuff failed. ===
Makefile wasn't created. Fix the errors above.
```

I cannot use make nor make install.

Comment: i've only encountered this when using jruby, can you give some specifics on environment. I take it you are using rvm? Which ruby?

Answer (score 80):

`rvm pkg install openssl` (older format - `rvm package install openssl`)
`rvm pkg install iconv` (older format - `rvm package  install iconv`)
`rvm remove 1.9.2`
`rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr,--with-iconv-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`

[Credit to http://www.isnull.com.ar/](http://www.isnull.com.ar/2010/11/ruby-rails-this-error-occurred-while.html)

Comment: FYI - If anybody gets "ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument: 'package' ( see: 'rvm usage' )", it's because 'Package' has been changed to 'pkg'.  So 'rvm pkg install XXXX' now.

Comment: This is actually a workaround. The proper fix would be to install a development version of the OpenSSL library. See answers below. On Debian/Ubuntu: apt-get install libssl-dev

Comment: (basically, either do rvm pkg install openssl, or do apt-get install  libssl-dev, then you do an rvm reinstall, see link in other answer too.)

Answer (score 13):

check this instruction http://rvm.io/packages/openssl/ - keep in mind that the **Quick fix** is just one block not the whole page.

Answer (score 7):

You have to install library for openssl/net/http run the following code and then install openssl and iconv.. Following code will work on UBUNTU..

`sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby1.9.1`  this is for ruby 1.9.1.

`sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby`       for ruby 1.8.x

Answer (score 7):

first check your rvm having the openssl package. Go to /usr/local/src/rvm/ruby-1.9.2-p290/

then go to ext/openssl.

type **ruby extconf.rb** 
If we found errors like this

```
enter code here
=== OpenSSL for Ruby configurator ===
=== Checking for system dependent stuff... ===
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for assert.h... yes
=== Checking for required stuff... ===
checking for openssl/ssl.h... no
=== Checking for required stuff failed. ===
Makefile wasn't created. Fix the errors above
```

Then install apt-get install libssl-dev.Once installed rub ruby **extconf.rb**.Now the openssl will get installed

Answer (score 6):

For ubuntu, I did the following:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
cd ruby-1.9(source directory used to install ruby)/ext/openssl
ruby extconf.rb
make
make install
```

Answer (score 3):

This solved the problem for me:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.2 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

And don't forget to change the ruby version to your version you are using. If you have an old rvm you may should update this at first too.

Answer (score 1):

I made

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

and done!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try running ruby-1.9.2-rc2 instead of head?
not sure if it will solve this issue or not, but I did have a lot of problems trying to run under head

pretty sure the the command would look like - rvm install 1.9.2-rc2

you will need to re-install rails again

Answer (score 0):

**This error means that your Ruby isn’t compiled with openssl.
Assuming that you use RVM, these are the steps to follow to fix this issue.**

**1.Install the openssl package**

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

**2.Remove the Ruby installation you’re using**

```
rvm remove 1.9.3
```

**3.And finally recompile Ruby with openssl**

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

**4.Everything should be working now. Don’t forget to:**

rvm use 1.9.3 --default

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps.

1. rvm get stable
2. brew install libyaml
3. rvm pkg install openssl
4. rvm install ruby-2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
5. rvm use ruby-2.0.0

if you already have ruby version use

rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr