# why would Rails be confused about which Ruby to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app that I developed on Windows. Now I'm bringing it over to a VM to get it running there before I deploy it. First I ran `rails c` and got

```
/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
```

OK I solved that with [Rails 3 - no such file to load -- openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464098/rails-3-no-such-file-to-load-openssl).

Then I ran `rails c` again and got:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /mnt/hgfs/AquaticKodiak/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_mySiteName_session'
                              ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
```

To me it looks like when it hit the first error Rails was using 1.9.3 and in the second one it was using 1.8. I'm pretty sure that `key: 'siteName'` won't work in 1.8. Does this mean that one of my gems is a 1.8 gem? I've done a `bundle install` and a `bundle update`, that didn't help.

Is Rails confused about which version of Ruby to use? When I run `ruby -v` I get `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]`. That seems correct.

Comment: Sounds like you have both Ruby versions. Try running rails directly from the 1.9 path `/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rails -c`

Comment: Worth a shot, I got `'report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) ` but when I list my gems Rails 3.1.3 is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the paths, it looks like you're using [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) and Linux on your VM. Since you followed the instructions for the openssl problem I'm guessing you may have corrupted your environment variables, and therefore disabled RVM, hence falling back to system default 1.8.

1. Open a new terminal and see if you can still run RVM `rvm list`. You should see a list of available ruby versions, if you don't then your RVM environment variables are messed up and you need to fix them (see the RVM docs).
2. Check in the project directory for the `.rvmrc` file and verify that you're using a version of ruby that's available on the system.
3. If yo use a list of ruby versions from `rvm list` select the one you want to use and execute `rvm use ruby-1.9.x-pxxx` just replace the x's with the one you want. You can also set the default ruby version to use with RVM's `default` command. Again, see the RVM docs.

Comment: rvm list shows one version only. .rvmrc doesn't exist in the project directory -- possibly because the app wasn't originally created on linux. I've done the set default already. At this point I've decided that something is Very Wrong with this VM so I'm going to start over with a fresh one and only install one flavor of Ruby.

Comment: The lesson I learned from this: use a VM, if things go south wipe the instance and start over fresh. I did eventually get it working but found that getting Rails running on Linux is full of pitfalls that can munge things up badly.