# rails server not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

I just bundle installed successfully and now I get this error when I start the rails server.

I have already tried to start the server by installing openssl and re-installing rvm.
I'm using rvm 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.10.

```
rony@linuxmint ~/Documents/trunk $ rails s
/home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:593:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/stripe-1.7.0/lib/stripe.rb:7
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/rony/Documents/trunk/config/application.rb:8
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /home/rony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p370/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464098/rails-3-no-such-file-to-load-openssl)

```
rvm pkg install openssl (older format - rvm package install openssl)
rvm pkg install iconv (older format - rvm package install iconv)
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr,--with-iconv-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Credit to http://www.isnull.com.ar/