# cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

In OS X in rvm how do I check if openssl is configured properly?
I get the `cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)`
And I have tried everything in [Rails 3 - no such file to load -- openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464098/rails-3-no-such-file-to-load-openssl) with no success.

Comment: latest solution for 2021:
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4819#issuecomment-595644550

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Check what rubies are installed:

```
rvm list
```

Then make sure to use one of the installed rubies:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p327
```

And test if `openssl` is available:

```
ruby -ropenssl -e "puts :OK"
```

It will print `OK` if `openssl` is enabled, otherwise you will get exception

### In case of exception =>

#### UPDATE:

new version of rvm has improved automation support:

```
rvm get stable
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall all --force
```

#### OLD:

run:

```
rvm requirements run force
rvm pkg remove
```

Followed by:

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

This instruction is not OSX specific, it will work on all platforms, although on OSX it will work best with HomeBrew, when it's not installed only list of required software will be shown and you need to install it manually.

Comment: I still get the same error. Also I've reinstalled ruby with sudo rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr

Comment: worked great, thanks!  (I didn't need to do the `rvm pkg remove` step)

Comment: I have been struggling with this install for 11+ hours. Yours are the only instructions that actually worked. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: I tried to get this working months ago and gave up.  Came back and saw this and it fixed my issue.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks!! It just helped me install compass via ruby :D

Comment: is there a way to do this without homebrew (which rvm relies on)?

Comment: i read the error logs for `rvm reinstall` but it's saying it can't find openssl...

Comment: This is no longer a working solution under OS X Catalina. Seems Apple really did a number on the build tools that Ruby requires...

Answer (score 21):

Many years later, the solution is changed because of brew upgrading, this works now:

```sh
# pull full brew git repo
git -C "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core" fetch --unshallow

# generate new brew tap repo
brew tap-new $USER/old-openssl

# extract openssl 1.0.2t forumlar to $USER/old-openssl
brew extract --version=1.0.2t openssl $USER/old-openssl

# install old openssl from $USER/old-openssl repo
brew install openssl@1.0.2t

# reinstall ruby
rvm reinstall 2.3.4 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl@1.0.2t`
```

Comment: I needed to add `--autolibs=disable` to `rvm reinstall` to prevent a brew update failure. Otherwise this works swimmingly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this finally solved the problem for me! I had to remove the '--unshallow' from the first command otherwise I got the error: "fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense"

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, I got MacOS 13 (March 2023)

Answer (score 15):

This is what worked for me after wasting more than a day on this

```
brew reinstall openssl@1.1
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc   
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
rvm install ruby-2.7.6 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1 --verify-downloads 1
```

Comment: Homebrew has changed location in new installs, meaning `/usr/local` should be changed to `/opt/homebrew`, as in `/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl\@1.1/bin/`.

Comment: Thanks, I was previously using "rvm package" to install OpenSSL and this is much better.

Comment: thank you so much. after wasting 2 days i found this more helpful .

Comment: This helped me! Along with the comment from @oligofren. Thank you so much :)) finally got a successful install

Comment: Right now an Edit is pending, but one could make the answer work with both old and new versions of Homebrew by just substituting `/usr/local/` with `$( brew --prefix)`.

Comment: work like a charm, thanks

Comment: Welcome to all!

Answer (score 11):

This help me :
https://gist.github.com/Irio/1496746

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl

$ rvm remove 1.9.3

$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Comment: Worked for me on Pop_OS 22.04 trying to get ruby-2.7.6 running. You can use `reinstall` instead of `remove` + `install` though, so all-in-all I ran:

`rvm pkg install openssl` followed by `rvm reinstall all --force --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr`

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-preview1  --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr --verify-downloads 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Install the openssl package

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

Remove the Ruby installation you're using

```
rvm remove 2.3.3
```

And finally recompile Ruby with openssl

```
rvm install 2.3.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest fix in 2023, if autolibs feature of rvm is not working for you.

Answer (score 4):

I uninstalled everything (rvm, rails, ruby, etc) on my macbook.

Installed homebrew

Installed rvm

Ran `rvm requirements run force`

Ran `rvm install rails`

`rails new sample_app`

`cd sample_app`

*Note:* `source 'https://rubygems.org'` is present in Gemfile, openssl is required!

`bundle install` **and it worked**!

**No need to specify:** `--with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr`

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this, **install openssl (preferably using brew)**.

Update Xcode to the latest version and **enable command line installations** using it.

Reinstall rvm using
`rvm reinstall all`

Note that `rvm reinstall all --force`
will delete all your previous installations of binaries/pkgs done using rvm.

Comment: If using rbenv this strategy also seems to work. The command is basically just to use the `force` option, `rbenv install 3.1.2 --force`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ruby is already installed, do the following:

```
rvm cleanup all

rvm reinstall all --force
```

Comment: Caution: `rvm reinstall all --force` can break your ruby installations

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and the error was fixed by opening new terminal session.

I am using `frum` ruby version manager.

Answer (score 0):

Download openssl and install it on a local path.

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc shared --prefix=$HOME/.local && make && make install
```

Then compile ruby with your open ssl compilation.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.local && make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answer above but not working for me.

In my case, I am very sure that I have openssl, but it keep show the error said:

> rspec cannot load such file -- openssl error
> Did you mean?  openssl/ssl

After 3 days, I solved by add `gem 'openssl'` in the Gemfile.

Answer (score -1):

`gem install openssl`
worked for me, but nothing has declared depending on the openssl, its weired

Answer (score -4):

Following command solved my issue
note 2.3.4 is the ruby version I am using, change as per your requirements

```
rvm reinstall 2.3.4 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Make sure that $rvm_path is properly set, with command `echo $rvm_path`. If this path is empty, check if your home folder has `.rvm` folder.

In this case use

```
rvm reinstall 2.3.4 --with-openssl-dir=~/.rvm/usr
```