# Ruby version `ruby-3.1.2' is not installed after spring stop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, ruby-build

Truly I don't get it what is wrong. I've got fresh project with Rails 7 and Ruby 3.1.2 which I thought I had installed successfully, based on my iTerm2 console:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin21]
```

But after firing up the command `spring stop` inside my project path I'm getting this weirdo:

```
➜  merchant-portal git:(main)$ spring stop
rbenv: version `ruby-3.1.2' is not installed (set by /Users/some_user/merchant-portal/.ruby-version)
```

What's going on?

I tried installing the Ruby 3.1.2 again but I'm getting another weirdo:

```
$ rbenv install 3.1.2

Downloading ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz
Installing ruby-3.1.2...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20220726)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/bw/rs138g1n5zv_qwn7_7kggc9r0000gq/T/ruby-build.20220801173008.20865.CTLYIi
Results logged to /var/folders/bw/rs138g1n5zv_qwn7_7kggc9r0000gq/T/ruby-build.20220801173008.20865.log

Last 10 log lines:
The Ruby yaml extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
Configure options used:
  --prefix=/Users/some_user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2
  --with-openssl-dir=/Users/some_user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/openssl
  --enable-shared
  --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/opt/readline
  CC=clang
  LDFLAGS=-L/Users/some_user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib
  CPPFLAGS=-I/Users/some_user/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/include
```

I've tried to reinstall `xcode` with:

```
$ rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
(...)
Done
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

And again reinstall Ruby 3.1.2 but it shows me the same error:

```
$ rbenv install 3.1.2
(...)
BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.5 using ruby-build 20220726)
(...)
Last 10 log lines:
The Ruby yaml extension was not compiled.
ERROR: Ruby install aborted due to missing extensions
(...)
```

I've also tried to:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl` --with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline` --with-libyaml-dir=`brew --prefix libyaml`" rbenv install 3.1.2
```

But it shows me the same error.

Comment: The issue is yaml. Install that through brew and try again.

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11636

Comment: Also do `brew update` && `brew doctor`

Comment: did you maybe install Ruby 3.1.2 NOT using `rbenv`? So `rbenv` doesn't know about it?

Comment: @Chiperific I tried use this solution from your link https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11636#issuecomment-290892884 but the result is the same. `brew update` also doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: To answer your last question - yes, I did `brew install ruby` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Make sure Ruby is installed via `rbenv`, otherwise `rbenv` probably won't find it. Also, if `brew install` isn't working for anything, then you'll need to check if you even have `brew` itself installed.

Comment: @Chiperific like I already wrote in my original question - I did `rbenv install 3.1.2`. Installs all the other stuff via brew so I assume I installed it a long time ago.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914720/882410