ssl version issue - ubuntu 24 cannot install gem with ruby 2.7.6 (rvm)
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24, I can no longer install gems for ruby 2.7.6, here is some output:
rvm list
=> ruby-2.7.6 [ x86_64 ]

now I try to bundle
bundle
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.3.18) required by your /home/kevin-chugh/Documents/code/opencaseware/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.3.18`

So now I try to install the gem:
gem install bundler:2.3.18
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

It seems like there is a general OpenSSL version with older rubies, anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Thanks,
Kevin

Is your Ruby compiled with openssl at all? Try to require it in an irb session to check. If not you may need to rebuild with a manually compiled version. You can also try to look here for some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845481/cannot-load-such-file-openssl-loaderror
